# How to find no. of digits of a large product

Tags: products

The question is:

> The product of 45,454,545,454,545 and 1,234 contains how many digits?

I dont know how to solve it other than typing it in my calculator, but that method is wrong too.

Answer (score 2):

The product is greater than $(4.0\times 10^{13})\times 10^3=4.0\times 10^{16}$ and less than $(5.0\times 10^{13})(2.0\times 10^3)=1.0\times 10^{17}$, hence it has $17$ digits.

Comment: This is a lot clearer than DRF's answer (same principle though).  Good answer!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen agreed, except it's (also) incorrect. the result has 17 digits not 18 since 1,234=$1.234*10^3$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: Thanks, although I have had a mistake in the second factor, which is between $1000$ and $2000$. I have corrected it.

Comment: You're still off by one in the answer though your math is correct now.

Comment: Could you explain to me how you got the numbers?

Comment: Since
$$4.0\times 10^{13}<45,454,545,454,545<5.0\times 10^{13}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 10^3<1234<2.0\times 10^3$$
we have
$$(4.0\times 10^{13})\cdot 10^3<45,454,545,454,545\cdot 1234<(5.0\times 10^{13})\cdot(2.0\times 10^3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use scientific notation. (i.e. write $45,454,545,454,545 =4.5454545454545*10^{13}$)

Comment: Those two numbers are not exactly equal.

Comment: @barakmanos Good point. Fixed